# Getting a list of files not handled by subversion

Tags: svn

I have checked out some files from subversion repository.

After building, there are a number of new files created.

How can I get the list of files that are handled which are not registered with this subversion repository?

I work on linux, and with subversion console version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svn st --no-ignore <path> | awk '/^\?/ {print $2;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any svn:ignore property set anywhere, then simple `svn stat` will show you a list of files. On this list, there should be files that are not handled by svn, they will be marked with '?'.

If you have svn:ignore set somewhere in your repository, then you can check every directory in your repository and check if there is svn:ignore set (`svn pl` will show you a list of properties of current dir), and then you can read the property with `svn propget svn:ignore`. Ignored files are not displayed in `svn stat`.